# How to check if the quantity inserted is greater than the new stock in my Datagridview Cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to create a function that will check if the quantity inserted is greater than the new stock in my Datagridview Cell `["New Stock"]` to prevent the data from execution.

[image]
[image]

```
double qty,totalprice,discount;
double.TryParse(txtqty.Text, out qty);
double.TryParse(txttotalprice1.Text, out totalprice);
double.TryParse(txtdiscount.Text, out discount);


//Boolean to check if he has row has been
bool Found = false;
if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
{

    // Check if the product Id exists with the same Price
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{

    if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value) == cmbproductcode.Text && Convert.ToString(row.Cells[3].Value) == txtprice1.Text)
    {
        //Update the Quantity of the found row
        row.Cells[5].Value = Convert.ToString(qty + Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[5].Value));
        row.Cells[7].Value = Convert.ToString(discount + Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[7].Value)); //txtqty
        row.Cells[8].Value = Convert.ToString(totalprice + Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[8].Value)); //txttotalprice                            
        Found = true;
        getprice();
    }

}
    if (!Found)
    {
        //Add the row to grid view                           
        getinfo();
    }

}
else
{
    //Add the row to grid view for the first time                   
    getinfo();

}
```

Comment: Your question needs clarification. The title… _”How to check if the quantity inserted is greater than the new stock”_  ... this is doable, however, I do not see any where in the posted code where this “check” is made. It would seem obvious that you would need to “check” this BEFORE executing the line of code… `row.Cells[5].Value = Convert.ToString(qty + Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[5].Value));` … that simply adds the value without checking if the value is greater than the new stock. In addition, what do you want to do if the value IS greater? Lastly “where” is this code run? Can you clarify this?

Comment: How is your DGV populated ? A datatable ? I would compute the desired value against the datatable. You have several options: the [compute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.compute?view=netframework-4.8) function or using LINQ for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 public double prev;
 private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
 {
            string cellValue;
            int i = e.RowIndex;
            cellValue = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            prev = Convert.ToDouble(cellValue);
 }
 private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
            string cellValue;
            int i = e.RowIndex;
            cellValue = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            
            double cur = Convert.ToDouble(cellValue);
           if(isvalid(prev,cur))
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = prev.ToString();
           else
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = cellValue;
 }


 private Boolean isvalid(double pr,double cur)
 {
            return cur > pr ? false : true;
 }
```